# Разработка под iOS в Windows

Tags: ipad, windows, ios, iphone

Что есть под винду, для более менее удобной разработки под iOS (iPhone/iPad) ?

Кроме эмуляторов и flash builder.

Comment: такой простой? ничего нет! только Mac

Comment: Если вам нужно писать приложения под iOS -  не мучайтесь и поставьте хакинтош.
А уже на нем можно пользоваться MonoTouch - он позволяет писать приложения на C#, например. Ну либо, если не боитесь, есть вариант юзать нативные фреймворки от Apple (на Objective-C писать т.е.).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Поставь виртуальную машину и на неё Mac OS. Не скажу что супер удобно, но зато намного проще чем шаманить над хакинтошем.

Comment: Ставил себе на VMware, мало что нормально работает. Анимации можно сказать вообще нет, да и вообще впечатления от работы ужасные.

Comment: А что вы хотели? Хотите анимацию, купите Mac -)

Answer (score 0):

Смотря что разрабатывать, для игр есть Uniti3d, для простых приложений со своим интерфейсом есть Flash CS5, для стандартных оконных(view) приложений нет ничего.
По крайнее мере я так знаю, я могу ошибаться.